# Unittest - Test for dict equality

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, dictionary

I am trying to do a unit-test but don't quite get why these 2 dicts show up as not equal. I was wondering if someone could give me an explanation for this occurrence. My code is...

```
import unittest

class TestEmailValidator(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        known_dict = {
            'debo@foobar.com': True,
            'debo@gmail.com': False
        }

        result_dict = {}

        for key in known_dict.keys():
            result_dict[key] = is_email_valid(key)

        # debugger results
        # result_dict = {
        #    'debo@foobar.com': True,
        #    'debo@gmail.com': False
        # }

        if self.assertEqual(known_dict, result_dict):
            print "is_email_valid passed"
        else:
            print "is_email_valid failed"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I get the same result for `assertEqual`, `assertEquals` and `assertDictEquals`. I have tried assigning `result_dict` to `known_dict` before the test, but that did not pass either.

It would be great if someone could point me to why this could be happening.

Comment: `is_email_valid` has not been included since it is pretty basic and returns True if string ends with `foobar.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the assert. All the `assertXYZ` methods don't return a boolean value, they just raise an exception if the assertion fails. As these methods don't return anything, they implicitly return `None`. When evaluating `None` as a boolean it's treated as false, and hence your test prints `is_email_valid failed`, even though the test actually passes.

Comment: Aha. This makes sense. Since, when I was debugging through the assert.. methods, it did not seem to throw any exceptions. Thank you for your help @mureinik.